# How do I prevent Brexit?

Tags: achievements, plague-inc

One of the achievements for Plague Inc is preventing Britain from leaving the EU. Occasionally while playing I see a pop up saying that Britain voted for a referendum to leave the EU, so I assume it has something to do with having the plague be known and infectious somewhere or lethal in the country. I managed to cause a Hard Brexit, but I haven't prevented Brexit. What sequence of events will prevent Brexit from occurring?

Comment: https://www.trueachievements.com/a232408/hard-brexit-achievement - would making this into an answer suffice?

Comment: @TimmyJim He says he's managed to cause Hard Brexit, so I don't think so? It sounds like he's trying to prevent it completely.

Comment: @Ash wasn't sure of how any of it works.

Comment: @TimmyJim idk. ill try and see if it works

Comment: I'm in the same boat that I don't know, but my guess based off how the game works, is just kill em before they can leave. Kind of like killing Madagascar before they can close the dock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the guide found [here](https://www.trueachievements.com/a232408/hard-brexit-achievement), it seems the best way to get the achievement is to take it in two steps:

**Step One:**

- Start in China
- Devolve any mutated traits that occur
- Wait for the pop up for the Brexit event.  It is title "UK votes for Brexit in referendum"
- Though not necessary, save your game at this point.  You may use this save to go back and get other Brexit related achievements.

**Step Two:**

- At this point, your disease should be spreading.  Wait until the UK gets infected with it.
- Once the UK is infected, evolve the following:

  - Insomnia
  - Paranoia
  - Cysts
  - Hyper Sensitivity
  - Cold Resistance 1
- After the UK gets infected, wait for a pop that looks like "XXX triggers Hard Brexit"

This will get you the Hard Brexit achievement.  However, if the UK gets completely infected before the "XXX triggers Hard Brexit" message, the Brexit will most likely be cancelled, which should unlock the other achievement "No Brexit."  Remember, if you mess up or something else goes wrong, you can reload your save.

[TL:DR](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37528499#37528499):

> basically wait for brexit referendum, get uk infected, upgrade those symptoms, get uk fully infected asap